# How to find which date is deselected in Bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to find a way to create an array with all selected dates but also if someone deselects the date, then it will remove that date from the array.

I've written the following JavaScript code to get selected and deselected dates.

I am using [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html).

```
$(function() {
  $('#disc_single_datepicker_1').datepicker().on('show', function(event) {
    DatePicker.hideOtherMonthDays();
  });
  var input_val = '';


  $('#disc_single_datepicker_1').on('changeDate', function(event) {
    //console.log(moment(event.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a'));
    var storage = new Array();

    var formatted_date = moment(event.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    console.log(formatted_date);
    if (formatted_date != '') {
      input_val = input_val + formatted_date + ",";
    }

    var exp = input_val.split(",");

    for (var i = 0; i < exp.length; i++) {
      if (exp[i] != '') {
        storage[i] = exp[i];
      }
    }
    console.log(storage);

  });


});
```

I am trying to find which date is deselected by the user from the datepicker.

I am also using the function which only shows the current month dates at a time. The function called `Datepicker.hideOtherMonthDays()` so it display like below:
[image]

Thanks in advance:) I've tried a lot to find a way but not sure how to do this.:)

Comment: Why do you need to know which one was deselected? Why can't you just recreate the array with the dates selected?

Comment: if you look at the code then i have change the event to changeDate event and also it's creating new array every single time but for example someone select 28,29,30 and I have array of 28,29,30 but if user change this to 28,30 then my array is not giving me this two dates but it gives me like 30 only not 28 & 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're going at it the wrong way.
Instead of knowing which was deselected, just recreate your array with the dates selected.

When you select a date, `datepicker` returns an event with all the dates selected.

If you print to console the actual event, you can see the dates property.

You can then loop though that array if needed.
This way you don't need to know which date was deselected.

Here's a minimal code example.

```
$('#disc_single_datepicker_1').datepicker({
    multidate: true
  }).on('show', function(event) {
    DatePicker.hideOtherMonthDays();
  }).on('changeDate', function(event) {
    var storage = new Array();
    //here's the magic
    for (var i = 0; i < event.dates.length; i++) {
      var formatted_date = moment(event.dates[i]).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      storage.push(formatted_date);
    }

    console.log(storage);
  });
```

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dL6j87ow/4/) (open the console).

PS: you might need to move the variable `storage` out of the scope if you wish to use it somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you so much I learn few things and I am now implementing this and if have any question then will ask you but really thanks for your help.